# apt update fails/ cannot install pkgs even after updating keys

Tags: ros, apt, ros-kinetic, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to run: `apt update` I encountered the same problem described in https://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-cannot-install-pkgs-key-not-working/

After following what @gvdhoorn suggested and trying to run `apt update` again, I get the following error:

```
Get:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [3.150 kB]
Err:31 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Writing more data than expected (3154295 > 3149706) [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

I tried this on two different PCs with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic installed. Is this something related to the repository having troubles or something wrong on my machine ? Does anyone else have the same problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329249/apt-update-fails/-cannot-install-pkgs-even-after-updating-keys/) by [matteolucchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44226/matteolucchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What solved the issue was to run `sudo apt-get clean` before running `sudo apt-get update`

---

Originally posted by [matteolucchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44226/matteolucchi/) with karma: 26 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-07-26**:
so if you problem is solved just close the questen